# selecting random rows with normal distribution based on a column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, select, random, union, distribution

**FULL DETAILS:**
let me explain more clear. this is a table including about 100 question. every question has a BooKRange property that shows from which part of the book, this question hast fetched with values 1,2,3,4. and there is another property called Level that shows level of the difficulty of the question with values 1,2,3,4,5. now i need to randomly select 20 question that have to include all four Book Ranges and all five levels with a normal distribution.

**please consider that i need to select distinct rows.**

thank you very much.

edit: added the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuesID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BookRange] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Level]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuesID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: I believe you mean "uniform distribution", not "normal distribution".  If you do mean "normal distribution", can you provide an example of what you mean and provide the average and standard deviation to characterize it?

Comment: normal means select 5 question from book range 1 and 5 question from book range 2 and so on by the way consider level property just like book range.

Comment: i want this solution to prevent selecting all 20 question from for example first quarter of the book. or select all level 1 questions.

Comment: . . A "normal distribution" is a very well defined term that refers to a particular sampling distribution that is fundamental to statistics.  You might be interested in reading the Wikipedia page on the topic.  In any case, I suspect that you want the second solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this query (assuming a uniform distribution) without doing a union.  You just need to specify the ordering correctly.

If you want to select 5 questions from each of the levels, then you can do so by assigning a sequential number to the questions in each level.  If these are assigned randomly, then you should meet the requirement of randomness for the levels:

```
with q as (
      select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [range] order by newid()) as seqnum
      from Question q
     )
select *
from q
where seqnum <= 5;
```

If you want to ensure that these is exactly one question for each level and range, but want the questions random, then do:

```
with q as (
      select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [range], [level] order by newid()) as seqnum
      from Question q
     )
select *
from q
where seqnum = 1;
```

By the way, `range` and `level` are reserved words in SQL Server.  In general, it is good practice to avoid using reserved words for the names of things like tables, columns, stored procedures, and so on.

Comment: oh that's working so sweet :D. Thank you very much. the syntax is almost not clear for me cause I'm new to sql and asp.net but the result is exactly what i wanted and what i needed. thank you and thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct id from table where level=1 order by rand() limit 5 union Select distinct id from table where level=2 order by rand() limit 5 union Select distinct id from table where level=3 order by rand() limit 5 union Select distinct id from table where level=4 order by rand() limit 5
```

Comment: thank you very much for answering first part of the question. but what about second part? i mean normal distribution based on `Range` column.

Comment: `Range` column has four value. 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Are you willing to use multiple queries.

Comment: if i want to tell more simple, i have to say i want 20 distinct question from all four levels and all four book range, with a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you havent provided any table schema, Assuming we have a table `dbo.Number` with One column with values from 1 - 30 you could do something like this ...

```
;With NthGroups
AS
 (
  SELECT  * , NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY Nums) Np
  FROM dbo.Number
 ),
Top25Perc
AS
 (
 SELECT TOP 5 * FROM NthGroups 
 WHERE NP = 1
 ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM NthGroups 
  WHERE NP = 2
  ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM NthGroups 
  WHERE NP = 3
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM NthGroups 
  WHERE NP = 4 
  ORDER BY NEWID()
 ) 
 SELECT * FROM Top25Perc
```

**Update**

Just read your comment in other answer and you have mentioned you have a column Range with values (1,2,3,4) , this makes query even simpler , you can do something like this

```
;With 
RandTop5
AS
 (
 SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName 
 WHERE [Range] = 1
 ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 2
  ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 3
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 4
  ORDER BY NEWID() 
 ) 
 SELECT * FROM RandTop5
```

Comment: thank you. i added the table to the code. i want to apply both filters together. both book range and level columns should be considered.

Comment: just add both filters in all the where clauses of the above query(2nd solution) and happy days :)

Comment: if i want to tell more simple, i have to say i want 20 distinct question from all four levels and all four book range, with a normal distribution,

Comment: @MahdiHesari Yep just add the book name and Level in each of the where clauses above and it will give you random questions from all books and all levels.

Comment: in first answer? or second?
sorry I'm new to asp and sql :(

Comment: @MahdiHesari 2nd answer

Comment: it will not work. if i edit like this: for example `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName 
 WHERE [Range] = 1 and [level]=1
 ORDER BY NEWID()`
it wont give me 5 question with all ranges and all levels. just give from level 1 and range 1. ok?

Comment: @MahdiHesari you need to do something like `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName WHERE [BookRange] = 1 AND [Level] = ?? and use UNION ALL` than other books and levels and so on ...

Comment: let me edit your answer and you see is that correct or not. give me a min

Comment: Is it the final answer?
what is that semi colon in first?
i want to select this in code behind. what is the exact `String` for `execute` in `sqlcommand` ?

Comment: `;` is used because I am using CTE (Common Table Expression) , and a CTE must be the 1st statement in a batch otherwise it throws an error therefore I used semi colon to terminate any prior sql statements. a very powerful tool in sql server introduced in sql 2005

Comment: @MahdiHesari brother the exact string for sql command will be the above 2nd solution once you have further tweaked it to suit for requirement :)

Comment: is this correct?
`SqlCommand1.CommandText = "With 
RandTop5
AS
 (
 SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName 
 WHERE [Range] = 1
 ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 2
  ORDER BY NEWID()
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 3
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName
  WHERE [Range] = 4
  ORDER BY NEWID() 
 ) 
 SELECT * FROM RandTop5"`

Comment: @MahdiHesari Obviously you have to replace the `TableName` with your actual table name which I believe is `[dbo].[Question]` and same goes for your Column names.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TableName WHERE [BookRange] = 1 AND [Level] = ??`
it gives error for this "??"

Comment: @MahdiHesari I used these question marks assuming you would know what values you are looking for, you would use the actual hardcoded value something you are actually looking for `[Level] = 1` or whatever your data type and data is in your  [Level] column .

Comment: @MahdiHesari and please if this answer provided enough information accept it :)

Comment: i didnt want to give the level value manually and this is why i said it wont work.

Comment: i think you misunderstood. please read the question again. thank you very much, and thank you again for giving me your time :)

Comment: @MahdiHesari Then you need to look closer into the 1st solution using NTILE() Function, Its difficult to guess what exactly your expectation are without having any sample data available.

Comment: let me explain more clear. this is a table including about 100 question. every question has a `BooKRange` property that shows from which part of the book, this question hast fetched with values 1,2,3,4. and there is another property called `Level` that shows level of the difficulty of the question with values 1,2,3,4,5. now i need to randomly select 20 question that have to include all four Book Ranges and all five levels with a normal distribution.